# Using variables in a makefile

Tags: python, mysql, bash, awk, makefile

I want my makefile to setup a mysql database. This is my procedure:

1. Retrieve `user`, `host`, `password` and `database` values from a `config.json` file with python, and store them in a `config` variable
2. Get each value stored in the `config` variable with awk (each value is separated by two spaces)
3. Run some mysql with these values

This is my script:

```
all:
    config=$(python3 -c 'import json; file = open("config.json"); config = json.load(file); file.close(); print(config["mysql"]["user"]+"  "+config["mysql"]["host"]+"  "+config["mysql"]["password"]+"  "+config["mysql"]["database"])'); \
    user=$(echo "$config" | awk -F  "  " '{print $1}'); \
    host=$(echo "$config" | awk -F  "  " '{print $2}'); \
    password=$(echo "$config" | awk -F  "  " '{print $3}'); \
    database=$(echo "$config" | awk -F  "  " '{print $4}'); \
    sudo mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $database; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $database.* TO '$user'@'$host' IDENTIFIED BY '$password'"
```

If I type this directly in my console it works fine. Why doesn't it work when running `make`?

This is my console output:

```
config=; config = json.load(file); file.close(); print(config["mysql"]["user"]+"  "+config["mysql"]["host"]+"  "+config["mysql"]["password"]+"  "+config["mysql"]["database"])'); \
user=; \
host=; \
password=; \
database=; \
sudo mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS atabase; GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, INDEX, ALTER ON atabase.* TO 'ser'@'ost' IDENTIFIED BY 'assword'; USE atabase;"
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `config=; config = json.load(file); file.close(); print(config["mysql"]["user"]+"  "+config["mysql"]["host"]+"  "+config["mysql"]["password"]+"  "+config["mysql"]["database"])'); user=; host=; password=; database=; sudo mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS atabase; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON atabase.* TO 'ser'@'ost' IDENTIFIED BY 'assword'"'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` does not make it from your Makefile into the shell it runs. Escape them using `$$` to make sure they get passed through as intended.

Answer (score 1):

`$` are used for Makefile variable reference.
So before passing it to the shell, make expands `$(python3 -c 'import json; file = open("config.json")` to nothing, since you are in fact asking for the expansion of the variable `python3 -c 'import json; file = open("config.json"` (which of course does not exist). Same story for the other lines. To avoid that, you'll need to escape `$` characters in the Makefile with another `$` character.